# loop repeating only once instead of being repeat for the number of items in Android

Tags: android, json, sqlite

I am having 11 items in json webservice .i am storing the details in sqlite and displaying them from the sqlite..So for that i have to check the ids of sqlite and TAG_ID of the web service.If the ids are not equal then i have to update their details in sqlite and display them for that i am using

```
   if(data_exist!=bookProduct.length()){
               Log.i("in update","m here");
               Cursor cursors = getRawEvents("select id from bcuk_book");
               try{
                     for (int i = 0; i < bookProduct.length(); i++) {
                     JSONObject c = bookProduct.getJSONObject(i);
                     String Bid = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                     ArrayList<String> mapId = new ArrayList<String>();
                        while(cursors.moveToNext())
                        {
                                Log.e("cursors",cursors.getString(0));
                                Log.i(Bid,Bid);
                                String csv = cursors.getString(0);
                                if(!cursors.getString(cursors.getColumnIndex(TAG_ID)).equalsIgnoreCase(c.getString(TAG_ID)))
                                        {
                                            Log.e("fas",Bid);
                                        }

                                        else
                                        {
                                            Log.e("enter","if case");
                                            cursors.moveToPosition(i);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    mapId.add(TAG_ID);
                                    Log.e(Bid,Bid);            
                             }

                     }
```

The problem here is iam able to get the TAG_ID only once in for loop but the while gets all the items .so the comparision is done only once rather than comparing for all the items.
How can i approach this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by calling cursors.moveToFirst(); after while loop

Comment: i already answer this in your previous question because without cursors.moveToFirst(); it's not possible to loop from cursor again

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do {
       Log.v("mylog", cursor.getString(0) + "," + cursor.getString(1) + "," + cursor.getString(2));
    }
    while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

use like this